# "To increase by" v/s "To increase to"

Tags: meaning, difference

I'm not a student with English as my mother tongue. I'm analysing an English text. I looked up in the dictionary the verb **"to increase"** and the noun **"increase"**.
I found these examples:

> - *Japan's industrial output increased **by** 2%*
> - *Our cross margin increased **to** 24%*

What is the difference between these two sentences?
Does **"by"** in the first sentence show that 2% is the maximum percentage of the increase?
Does **"to"** in the second sentence show that there has been a progress in the action?
Has the level of the increase started hypothetically, for example, from5%, then 10%, then 15% and now is 24%?

Concerning the noun **'increase'** I found these examples:

> - *An **increasing** number OF customers shop online.*
> - *Any **increase in** production would be helpful.*

Why is the preposition **"of"** used in the first example and **"in"** in the second?

Answer (score 4):

You can have an amount of something.  It might be money or might be anything else.  But I will use money as an example. So imagine I have £50 on Monday and on Tuesday I have £75. :)

> The amount of money has increased.
>
> It has increased to £75. That is the final amount.
>
> It has increased by £25, that is the change in money

But £25 is 50% of £50 so I could also say

> It has increased by 50%.

I could also say "It is 150% of the value on Monday"

Now suppose I have something that *is measured in %*, for example the unemployment rate is measured as a percentage of the population.

In January it was 10%, in February it is 24%

> It has increased to 24%  (The final rate is 24%)

Now in this situation using "by" often causes mathematical mistakes.  You should say

> It has increased by 14 percentage points.

But many people say "it has increased by 14%" even though this is mathematically confusing

In your examples the Japanese industrial output is measured in Yen.  There has been an increase. The change in output is 2/100 of the previous output.

In the second example, the cross margin was less than 24%.  Now it is 24%

Concerning increase.  We use "a number of" which justifies the use of "of". We also use "of" with a value

We use "in" with the thing that is increasing

> An increase of 700 in the number of passengers.

> An increase of 30% in the size of hamburgers.

Comment: upvoted, but it only answers the first bit of the question ;)

Comment: I think the second part could be a separate question, but I've briefly addressed it now.

Comment: "It has increased to 24% (The final rate is 25%)" ?

Comment: fixéd..........

Answer (score 1):

> Japan's industrial output increased BY 2% (it gained 2%)
>
> Our cross margin increased TO 24% (from a lower percentage which can be 23% or less, it has reached the percentage of 24% )

Then

> An increasing number OF customers shop online.

(the number OF customers increased - here OF has nothing to do with ***increasing***. "increasing" is merely used as an adjective describing "number" and means *A number OF customers that is increasing*.)

> Any increase IN production would be helpful.

The expression is ***to increase in something*** (be it quantity or number). You use OF for percentages though. For example:

> This year we witnessed a surprising increase ***OF*** 20% ***IN*** sales.

Comment: You have made a mathematically confusing example.  An increase from 46% to 48% is an increase of two percentage points, but it may not be a two percent increase, because 2% of 48% is not 2%....Lots of people get this confused. especially journalists.

Comment: @JamesK: Oops, I was never good at maths.

Answer (score 1):

*To* identifies a target or destination.  If X is 25, and then you increased X to 50, X is now 50.

*By* identifies something that is used, but isn't the "final product".  If X is 25, and then you increased X by 50, X is now 75.

---

> An increasing number OF customers shop online

> Any increase IN production would be helpful

*Of X* is used because *customers* is countable (you would ask "how many customers" and not "how much") and each X is considered an independent individual.

*In X* is used because *production* is probably not countable (you would ask "how much production" and not "how many production") and there's no "each production".

Answer (score 0):

Here are my short explanations:

- "increased by" means that before increasing it was 100$, and after increasing it is 150$, so you would say:

> The money in the bank account **increased by** 50$

- "increased to" means that before increasing it was 100$, and after increasing it is 150$, so you would say:

> The money in the bank account **increased to** 150$