# Difference between increase by and increase to

Tags: meaning

> They increased my wage by three times.

> They increased my wage to three times as much as previous amount.

Are there any difference between two sentences in terms of meaning?

Comment: They mean the same thing: **new wage = old wage x 3**

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270522/to-increase-by-v-s-to-increase-to).
Shortly, you can think of increase (by/to) this way:
Increased by (rate of change);
Incresed to (total amount);

In your setences:

1. The rate of change is 3 times your previous wage, then now you have a total of: 1+3=4 wages.
2. The total amount of your wage is now 3 times what it was before, so, a total of: 3 wages

Comment: No. They both mean: **new wage = old wage x 3**. There's nothing about "rate of change" in the question, and even if the wage is multiplied, there's still only one wage, not three or four.

Comment: The link I added talks about that, not with such terms but meaning so, rate of change/ increase in the amount of money/ x% raise, you name it. The "equation" is meant to be: "Your wage is now three times the amount it was before (the pay rise is a distinction point between old and new wage)"